# How do I identify this JSON-like data structure?

Tags: json, database, sql-server-2008, custom-data-type

I just came across a JSON wannabe that decides to "improve" it by adding datatypes... of course, the syntax makes it nearly impossible to google.

```
a:4:{
  s:3:"cmd";
  s:4:"save";
  s:5:"token";
  s:22:"5a7be6ad267d1599347886";
}
```

Full data is... much larger...

The first letter seems to be **a** for array, **s** for string, then the quantity of data (# of array items or length of string), then the actual piece of data.

With this type of syntax, I currently can't Google meaningful results.  Does anyone recognize what god-forsaken language or framework this is from?

**Note**: some genius decided to stuff this data as a single field inside a database, and it included critical fields that I need to perform aggregate functions on.  The rest I can handle if I can get a way to parse this data without resorting to ugly serial processing.

If this can be parsed using MSSQL 2008 that results in a view, I'll throw in a bounty...

Answer (score 1):

I would parse it with a UDF written in .NET - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions

You can either write a custom aggregate function to parse and calculate these nutty fields, or a scalar value function that returns the field as JSON.

I'd probably opt for the latter in the name of separation of concerns.